# Automapper with different type of nested objects

Tags: automapper

I have a destination class  like below

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set;}
}

public class Delivery
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

I've to map ProductName in above class from below source class

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDelivery> Deliveries { get; set; }
}
public class OrderDelivery
{
    public List<OrderDeliveryDetails> ProductDeliveryDetails { get; set; }
}
public class OrderDeliveryDetails
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

How I can do this using Automapper.
(Note: Please Don't confuse with the `List<OrderDeliveryDetails>` in `OrderDelivery`class. It is because, it may have child products as well, but i need to take parent `ProductName`only)

Answer (score 0):

Well if by taking the parent ProductName you mean the first, you can try something along these lines (otherwise I might've misunderstood your question and you can ignore my answer):

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration : Profile
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _mapper;

    public AutoMapperConfiguration(IConfiguration mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _mapper.CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>
           .ForMember(d => d.OrderId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.OrderId))
           .ForMember(d => d.Deliveries, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Deliveries));

        _mapper.CreateMap<OrderDelivery, Delivery>
           .ForMember(d => d.ProductName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ProductDeliveryDetails.First().ProductName));
    }
}
```

and then simply

```
_mapper.Map(orderDto);
```

(this is, provided you have all the wireup needed to use AutoMapper).